# For pairs of elements, count the ones whose XOR value is a sum of two primes

Tags: c++, primes, c++14

An array is given with 'n' Values ( n <= 10^5 ) ; we have to calculate xor of each pair of elements and count those pairs whose xor can be written as sum of two prime numbers with the same parity(both odd or even). My code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
cin.tie(NULL);
int testCases;
cin >> testCases;
for (int i = 0; i < testCases; i++) {
long long n;
cin >> n;

long long input;
vector<long long> even, odd;
for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    cin >> input;
    if (input % 2 == 0) {
        even.push_back(input);
    } else {
        odd.push_back(input);
    }
}
long long answer = 0;

// even traversal
for (auto i = even.begin(); i != even.end(); i++) {
    for (auto j = i + 1; j != even.end(); j++) {
        if ((*i ^ *j) % 2 == 0 && (*i ^ *j) > 2) {
           // cout<<"required pair - "<<*i<<" "<<*j<<endl;
            answer++;
        }
    }
}

// odd traversal
for (auto i = odd.begin(); i != odd.end(); i++) {
    for (auto j = i + 1; j != odd.end(); j++) {
        if ((*i ^ *j) % 2 == 0 && (*i ^ *j) > 2) {
           // cout<<"required pair - "<<*i<<" "<<*j<<endl;
            answer++;
        }
    }
}

cout << answer << endl;
 }
 return 0;
 }
```

but this code gives O(n^2) as its complexity ( in the worst case ). Can anyone suggest a better solution ?

Comment: The word "parity" has two meanings.  In the *mathematical* sense it's just odd or even.  In the *computer science* sense it's the mathematical parity of the sum of bits of the binary representation.  Which is yours?

Comment: With the same parity as what? it is unclear to me if the primes must have the same parity (see Edwards definition above) or the original values must have the same parity or a third?

Comment: @Edward and @surt the post says this `...parity(both odd or even)`  does this not define which meaning the OP Suggests?

Comment: @Malachi: It's insufficient because *odd* and *even* are used to describe both kinds of parity.  Also consider the two 3-bit values `110` (6 decimal) and `101` (5 decimal).  They have opposite *mathematical* parity but the same *computer science* parity.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! This question is incomplete. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question. The more you tell us about what your code does and what the purpose of doing that is, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you. [Questions should include a description of what the code does](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1226)

Answer (score 2):

- An `xor` of two even numbers is necessarily even. An `xor` of two odd numbers is necessarily even. Therefore, testing for `(*i ^ *j) % 2 == 0` is redundant.
- Do not brute force. Use some math:

  *If*, for the sake of simplicity, we consider `1` as a prime (thus avoiding a special case of `2`), any pair of distinct evens (and any pair of distinct odds) contributes to a tally. By a pure combinatorial argument, if an array length is \$N\$, and the element appears \$K\$ times, there are \$K \cdot (N-K)\$ such contributions. Sorting the array will streamline the process.

  Since 2 *is* a special case, notice that the elements `xor`ing to 2 must be adjacent in the sorted array. It only makes a small complication to the above algorithm.
- Your approach is - correctly - based on the Goldbach's conjecture. I strongly recommend an introductory comment.